# Absolute continuity in Banach spaces

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, continuity, banach-spaces

Does absolute continuity of a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow E$ into some Banach space also ensures (i) measurability and (ii) differentiability almost everywhere, like it does on ${\bf R}$?

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are measurable since they are continuous. I found a counterexample to differentiability though, but forgot the source, it was $$f:[0,1]\rightarrow L^1([0,1]):t\mapsto{\bf 1}_{[0,t]}$$